# Connection refused exceptions with socket. Java

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I've been following O'Reilly's Head First book with connecting sockets for a simple chat client. It is giving me a list of exceptions which I have posted below along with the program. I've run through it a few times and cannot see where I've gone wrong. Thank you!

```html
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleChatClientA {

 JTextField outgoing;
 PrintWriter writer;
 Socket sock;

 public void go() {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Generation X Chat Client");
  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

  outgoing = new JTextField(20);
  JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
  sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
  mainPanel.add(outgoing);
  mainPanel.add(sendButton);
  frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
  setUpNetworking();
  frame.setSize(400, 500);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 }

 public void setUpNetworking() {
  try {
   sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 36555);
   writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
   System.out.println("Network established.");
  } catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
   try {
    writer.println(outgoing.getText());
    writer.flush();
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }

   outgoing.setText("");
   outgoing.requestFocus();
  }
 }

 public static void main (String[] args) {
  new SimpleChatClientA().go();
 }
}
```

The exceptions are here:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleChatClientA.setUpNetworking(SimpleChatClientA.java:32)
    at SimpleChatClientA.go(SimpleChatClientA.java:23)
    at SimpleChatClientA.main(SimpleChatClientA.java:55)
```

Something like this I have for the server, because it doesn't show a ServerSocket connection in the book program. Is this correct? I compile and run this server one, then compile and run the above code in command prompt:

```html
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPServer {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
   try {
    ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket(5000);
    System.out.println("Waiting for TCP client connection on port 5000.");

    while (true) {
     Socket sock = Server.accept();
     System.out.println("The client has connected successfully.");
    }
   } catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there a server running on that port? The exception is indicating that there isn't.

Comment: As I am still in the process of learning, I've edited my question to post a code of what I've been doing and using as the server. If it is incorrect, please correct me :)

Comment: It's really hard to connect to the server when it's listening on port `5000` and  you're trying to connect to port `36555`.

Comment: Omg thanks I'm so clumsy. Been at it for a while too! xD